# linear regression with lag

Tags: r, linear-regression

I have the following mock data, which is constructed in a way to reflect the fact that the columns `use` and `budget` **don't have the same length**:

```
year <- seq(2010, 2019, 1)
budget <- runif(10)
df1 <- data.frame(year, budget)

years2 <- seq(2010, 2019, 3)
use <- runif(4)
gender <- c("w", "w", "w", "w")
df2 <- data.frame(years2, gender, use) %>% rename(year = years2)

df_corr <- df2 %>% full_join(df1, by = "year") %>% arrange(year)
```

I have succeeded in filtering out the `NA` and regressing `use` on `budget` for the same year.

I would like to regress `use` on `budget` from the previous year. If for instance the `use` increases from 2010 to 2013, see what happens to the `budget` from 2010 to **2012**, as it might take a year for the budget to affect the use.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I'm slightly confused by your example data and the way you state the problem so let me give you some reproducible data and see if I am anywhere near what you're looking for...

```r
library(dplyr)

set.seed(2020)  
group <- rep(letters[1:10], each = 10)
year <- rep(2010:2019, times= 10)
budget <- runif(100, min = 10, max = 100)
use <- runif(100)
df <- data.frame(group, year, budget, use)
glimpse(df)
#> Rows: 100
#> Columns: 4
#> $ group  <chr> "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b…
#> $ year   <int> 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 20…
#> $ budget <dbl> 68.22126, 45.48032, 65.66516, 52.92020, 22.24875, 16.06459, 21…
#> $ use    <dbl> 0.42512874, 0.26608799, 0.72619972, 0.93059516, 0.25023194, 0.…
df <- df %>% group_by(group) %>% mutate(prev_year_use = lag(use, order_by = year))
glimpse(df)
#> Rows: 100
#> Columns: 5
#> Groups: group [10]
#> $ group         <chr> "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "b", …
#> $ year          <int> 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2…
#> $ budget        <dbl> 68.22126, 45.48032, 65.66516, 52.92020, 22.24875, 16.06…
#> $ use           <dbl> 0.42512874, 0.26608799, 0.72619972, 0.93059516, 0.25023…
#> $ prev_year_use <dbl> NA, 0.42512874, 0.26608799, 0.72619972, 0.93059516, 0.2…
lm(budget ~ use, data = df)
#> 
#> Call:
#> lm(formula = budget ~ use, data = df)
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#> (Intercept)          use  
#>      50.604        7.639
lm(budget ~ prev_year_use, data = df)
#> 
#> Call:
#> lm(formula = budget ~ prev_year_use, data = df)
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#>   (Intercept)  prev_year_use  
#>         47.60          10.66
```

Comment: one of my issues is that the column `use` and the column `budget` don't have the same length (thus my reproducible example) and there are NA. When regressing the data on common years I can filter out the NA and have a reduced data frame with the same column length, but since I would like to include a lag in the regression I can't do it that way.